# proc Sql Case Statement returning Null values

Tags: sql, sas

Can someone look at my Proc Sql and tell me why the below case staement is returing Null values in the data? I have never seen this, there are no errors, the code runs and the case statement value (Enrollment_Period) in the data is Null. Any ideas or solutions ?

```
proc sql;
        create table Data_Active as
           select distinct
                e.cova_evnt_efcv_dt as cova_evnt_efcv_dt Format=MMDDYYS10.,
                e.cova_evnt_eprn_dt as cova_evnt_eprn_dt Format=MMDDYYS10.,
                year(cova_evnt_efcv_dt) as Year,
                month(cova_evnt_efcv_dt) as Month,
                Case
                when 'Month' = "1" then "AEP"
                when 'Month' = "2" then "OEP"
                when 'Month' = "3" then "OEP"
                when 'Month' = "4" then "LockIn"
                when 'Month' = "5" then "LockIn"
                when 'Month' = "6" then "LockIn"
                when 'Month' = "7" then "LockIn"
                when 'Month' = "8" then "LockIn"
                when 'Month' = "9" then "LockIn"
                when 'Month' = "10" then "LockIn"
                when 'Month' = "11" then "LockIn"
                when 'Month' = "12" then "LockIn"
                end as Enrollment_Period,
```

Comment: single quotes are treated as string so you compare the text month  to everything

Comment: There isn't any matching case here. 'Month' is string literal Month and "1", "2" ... mean columns named 1, 2, 3 ... which unlikely you have. Also then "AEP", "OEP" column names doesn't make any sense. Probably you meant to write : when Month = 1 then 'AEP' when Month = 2 then 'OEP' ...

Comment: @nbk if I remove the quotes from the Month I get an error that ERROR: The following columns were not found in the contributing tables: Month. SAS recognizes Month as a column if I don't put it in quotes

Comment: you must use MONTH(cova_evnt_efcv_dt) to get a month from, no shortcuts

Comment: @nbk, thank you!! MONTH(datecolum) worked

Comment: Or put the keyword calculated in front of it, ie `calculated month in ('2', '3') then 'OEP'`